# Why does Eclipse show a Git repo for a Working Set?

Tags: eclipse, git

Whenever I open a project in Eclipse (4.2.1) that is connected to a Git repo, the Git repo description [Name branch] is displayed by the Working Set that project is in.

Example:

[image]

If I close the TestSlide project (that has the repo of the same name), the `[TestSlide master]` will be gone. And when I open another Git-connected project, then *its* repo name/branch will be printed beside the Working Set.

And when there are several Git-connected projects opened in the Working Set (all coincidentally pointing to master branch), this is shown:

[image]

Even though there are several projects in the same Working Set that are connected to SVN repos, never are their repo names shown beside the Working Set name.

Somehow I believe this is not intended (by Eclipse), so is it something I "misconfigured" in Eclipse so I can fix it to get rid of this annoyance?

Comment: It's a "label decorator" for the source control provider, you can change its settings in the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I'm aware of that. But changing anything there does not solve my problem. If I remove Text Decorations from Projects, then the Working Set has no decoration, but neither do projects --> unacceptable.

Comment: I understand now; you want the label decoration on for the projects, but off for the working sets.

Comment: Did you find a solution? It's not a real problem, but a bit disturbing.

Comment: Three years later, still no solution. I have reported the issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533132.